# How do you compile Winff?

Tags: compilation, ffmpeg, lazarus, avconv

I downloaded the [WinFF](http://winff.org) source code in the hopes the new version would solve a segfault.

It's sitting, extracted, in its folder. But I see no `./configure`, nothing `make` would know what to do with, no binaries, and no compilation instructions:

```
$ ls
AUTHORS        COPYING           README-Presets.txt  unit2.lfm  unit4.pas  winff.1      winff.rc
changelog.txt  docs              README.txt          unit2.pas  unit5.lfm  winff.ico
clean.bat      languages         RESOURCES.RC        unit3.lfm  unit5.pas  winff-icons
clean.sh       potranslator.pas  unit1.lfm           unit3.pas  unit6.lfm  winff.lpi
COMPILE.TXT    presets.xml       unit1.pas           unit4.lfm  unit6.pas  winff.lpr
```

Does anyone know how I can try to actually compile the code?

All we get is a README.txt:

> Winff -  graphical video and audio batch converter using ffmpeg or
>   avconv Copyright  © 2006-2012 Matthew Weatherford 
>   http://www.winff.org
>
> This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
>   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at
>   your option) any later version.
>
> This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
>   WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
>   General Public License for more details.
>
> You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>   along with this program.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
>
> WinFF is a GUI for the command line video converter FFmpeg or avconv.
>
> Get the latest ffmpeg builds and source from http://ffmpeg.org/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in COMPILE.TXT:

> winff is compiled with `lazbuild -B winff.lpr` or manually in the
>   Lazarus IDE.